# Very simple jQuery plugin fails and the console does not display errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slicknav

I'm using a plugin that turns your responsive navigation. I have used with other sites and works well:
[SlickNav jquery plugin](http://slicknav.com/)

**1) First of all the menu load properly:**
[image]

**2)One second later shows the HTML white and menu text only:**
[image]

The Chrome and Firefox console don´t show errors... so that everything works.

Of course, I'm using the correct version of jQuery and scripts are properly loaded.

What is happening?

Thank you very much.

This is the file where I call the scripts:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://rp-static.com/common/js/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://rp-static.com/common/js/jquery_modules/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://rp-static.com/common/js/RP_Traductor.js?1.0"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.slicknav.min.js"></script>

<!-- Aviso navegador viejo -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://rp-static.com/common/js/noie6/noie6.js"></script>
<style>
.tabrow li{
    width:93px;
    float:left;
    padding-top:4px;
}
</style>
<![endif]-->

<script>
<? if ($dicc != ''){?>
var dicc = new Dicc();
dicc.init('<?=$dicc?>','<?=$_SESSION['lng']?>');
<? } ?>
$(document).ready(function()
{   

    $('img').bind("contextmenu",function(e){return false;}); 

    // This adds placeholder support to browsers that wouldn't otherwise support it. 
    jQuery(function() {
       jQuery.support.placeholder = false;
       test = document.createElement('input');
       if('placeholder' in test) jQuery.support.placeholder = true;
    });

    $(function() {
       if(!$.support.placeholder) { 
          var active = document.activeElement;
          $(':text').focus(function () {
             if ($(this).attr('placeholder') != '' && $(this).val() == $(this).attr('placeholder')) {
                $(this).val('').removeClass('hasPlaceholder');
             }
          }).blur(function () {
             if ($(this).attr('placeholder') != '' && ($(this).val() == '' || $(this).val() == $(this).attr('placeholder'))) {
                $(this).val($(this).attr('placeholder')).addClass('hasPlaceholder');
             }
          });
          $(':text').blur();
          $(active).focus();
          $('form:eq(0)').submit(function () {
             $(':text.hasPlaceholder').val('');
          });
       }
    });

    $('#btn_top_jessica').click(function(){
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(".barra_superior").offset().top
        }, 750); 
    });

        window.___gcfg = {lang: 'es'};

      (function() {
        var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
        po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
      })();
});
</script>

    <script>

    function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays){
        var d = new Date();
        d.setTime(d.getTime()+(exdays*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "expires="+d.toGMTString();
        document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires+"; path=/";
    }

    function getCookie(c_name){
        var c_value = document.cookie;
        var c_start = c_value.indexOf(" " + c_name + "=");
        if (c_start == -1)
          c_start = c_value.indexOf(c_name + "=");

        if (c_start == -1)
          c_value = null;
        else
        {
            c_start = c_value.indexOf("=", c_start) + 1;
            var c_end = c_value.indexOf(";", c_start);
            if (c_end == -1)
                c_end = c_value.length;
            c_value = unescape(c_value.substring(c_start,c_end));
        }
        return c_value;
    }

    function acceptCookies(e) {
        setCookie("aviso_cookies","3",30); 
        e.parentNode.style.display="none";
    }

    $(window).load(function()
    {
        //Responsive Menu
//      $(function(){
//          $('.menu-responsive').slicknav();
//      });

        if (getCookie('aviso_cookies') == null || parseInt(getCookie('aviso_cookies')) < 3) {
            var aviso_cookies = getCookie('aviso_cookies') == null? 0 : parseInt(getCookie('aviso_cookies'))+1;
            setCookie('aviso_cookies',aviso_cookies,30);
            $('body').prepend('<div class="cookies_msg">Utilizamos cookies propias y de terceros para mejorar nuestros servicios, personalizar tu experiencia y optimizar nuestra publicidad. <br>Tienes toda la información en nuestra <a href="politica-de-cookies">política de cookies</a>: si continúas navegando, consideraremos que la aceptas. <span style="cursor:pointer;color:blue;text-decoration:underline;" onclick="javascript:acceptCookies(this);"> Cerrar </span></div>');
        }
    });

    </script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://rp-static.com/common/js/jquery_modules/memu/jquery.memu-0.1.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://rp-static.com/common/js/jquery_modules/memu/memu-0.1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

**The responsive menu call is:**

```
//Responsive Menu
        $(function(){
            $('.menu-responsive').slicknav();
        });
```

Comment: Care to provide some code ?

Comment: or alternatively a demo or live site?

Comment: I edited the main post

Comment: so whats the issue? what isnt working?

Comment: so is the entire html being replaced with just that string?

Comment: Exactly @DLeh  . After loading the plugin, my html shows only white